# C array of ObjC objects as a Function argument

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-2.0

Whenever I am passing an argument of Objective C type A to my function then everything is alright:

```
- (void) f:(id<A>)argument
```

However, when it's an array of the same object type, Xcode requires that I add a strong attribute as:

```
- (void) f:(__strong id<A> [])argument
```

Any idea why is that?

Comment: (1) What does Xcode say? (2) What's your definition of `A`, is it a `protocol`?

Comment: Yes, A is a protocol. I don't think A makes any difference here. The distinction is between having an object vs. having a C array of objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARC - why do object pointers require explicit ownership type in function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124440/arc-why-do-object-pointers-require-explicit-ownership-type-in-function-definit)

Comment: @blld Agree, it seems a duplicate; however, the answer there is not satisfying.